# Linux: how to look for files with a certain extension in hierarchy and execute command whenever one is found?

Tags: linux, find

I have a directory hierarchy, whose names do not follow a pattern. E.g.

parent

- bcgegec

  - hfiwehfiuwe

    - huiwwuifegeufg
    - whegwgefyfeg
  - hfeohfeiofe
  - chidchuehugfe
- dedewdewf

  - tegtgetg
  - gtgetgtg

and so on.

Inside some of such directories there is a file with "gr" extension. I need to find each of such files, cd to its dir and execute "gnuplot" command having the .gr file as argument. I tried the following to nest two find commands, but the {} of the inner one does not work as I need. The outer find should iterate for every directory, and the inner find should look for the presence of the .gr file.

```
find $parentDir -type d -exec sh -c '(cd {} && find . -maxdepth 1 -name *.gr -exec /usr/bin/gnuplot {} \;)' \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
find . -type f -name "*.gr" -execdir /usr/bin/gnuplot {} \;
```

Read through `man find` for other useful information.